# Javascript/NodeJS, get the length of a map

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

so I have a small problem returning the size of a map :

```
var siteRoomMap = new Map;
// (algorithm to fill the map)

console.log('in start');
console.log(siteRoomsMap);
console.log(siteRoomsMap.size);
```

and this is what i get in the terminal :

```
in start

{
    '1': {
        siteNumber: 1,
        roomsMap: {
            '1': [Object],
            '2': [Object],
            '3': [Object]
        },
        siteState: false
    },
    '2': {
        siteNumber: 2,
        roomsMap: {
            '1': [Object]
        },
        siteState: false
    }
}

0
```

I mean, my map clearly has 2 keys/values in it, but it always returns `0`.
I tried `map.length` but I get an `undefined` (probably cause `.length` doesn't exist for a map ? )

I could write a function my self that would look like that and call it on my map with

```
size = myfunction(siteRoomsMap);

var myfunction = function(data){
    for (i in data) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
};
```

but why can't I use `.size` ? I looked in the doc and it clearly says it returns the number of element in the map ???

Comment: Yes. According to the [Map MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the length property's value is 0. Yes that function you provided would work, but you would need to use [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to make sure that you don't count the length of prototype values

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @patrick barr: yes length is always zero. But size shouldnt be...

Comment: maybe include your "map algorithm"? we might find something there

Comment: also, you declared `siteRoomMap` but you are doing `console.log(siteRoomsMap);`. see the extra `s`? `Room` vs `Rooms`?

Comment: Where have you added enteries to siteRoomsMap?

Answer (score 3):

Use [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) method instead of block operator when inserting something.

Answer (score -1):

I can't seem to reproduce your problem:

```js
var map = new Map(),
    obj1 = {
        siteNumber: 1,
        roomsMap: {
            '1': [Object],
            '2': [Object],
            '3': [Object]
        },
        siteState: false
    },
    obj2 = {
        siteNumber: 2,
        roomsMap: {
            '1': [Object]
        },
        siteState: false
    };

//set key-value pairs here
map.set('1', obj1);
map.set('2', obj2);

console.log(map);
console.log(map.size);
```

So I think there must be something wrong with how you are filling your `Map`.